# By your experience exists?

Tags: prepositions

What is the correct for the following sentence:

> - By your experience, what do you think attracts tenants?
> - From your experience, what do you think attracts tenants?
> - In your experience, what do you think attracts tenants?

Context: asking someone who is an expert in the real estate industry

Of course I can write things like "considering/regarding your experience...", but my question is specifically about the aforementioned examples.

Comment: Don't have time for an answer/explanation, but `From`/`In` are basically interchangeable in this context - though `In` is more natural/correct. As a native speaker, `By` sounds very odd.

Comment: [Google's ngram viewer](https://books.google.com/ngrams/graph?content=by+your+experience%2Cfrom+your+experience%2Cin+your+experience&year_start=1800&year_end=2019&corpus=26&smoothing=3&direct_url=t1%3B%2Cby%20your%20experience%3B%2Cc0%3B.t1%3B%2Cfrom%20your%20experience%3B%2Cc0%3B.t1%3B%2Cin%20your%20experience%3B%2Cc0) is a great place to find answers to this type of question

Comment: Thanks guys!...

Answer (score 0, accepted):

"In my experience" and "in your experience" are very very common phrases, almost fixed phrases. So much so that the standard online initialism "IME" stands for "In my experience".

"From your experience" is reasonably common, although far less common than forms using "in".  It is often used when asking for a formal opinion from an expert, such as in court testimony.

The phrase "by your experience" is quite rare, and would be thought odd by most native speakers of AmE at least.

Comment: Thanks.........

Comment: @Lambie  Yes, a typo now fixed. Thank you.